# How to pass a parameter into a form upon creating?

Tags: 8, forms

I have a form, which contains an additional field. And I want to initiate the field via the form constructor.

```
class ServicesForm extends FormBase {

    private $service_type;

    public function __constructor($_service_type){
        $this->service_type = $_service_type;
    }
```

The form is created in a controller.

```
class ServicesController extends ControllerBase {

    public function getServices($service_type){
        $data['form'] = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('\Drupal\palom_services\Form\ServicesForm');

        return $data;
    }
```

Could you clarify me, how to pass the parameter $service_type to the form inside the controller method ?

Maybe, should I do it without FormBuilder and getForm ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add it to your form's `buildForm` method signature:

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $arg = NULL) {
  // Use $arg
}
```

Then literally pass it to the form builder's `getForm` method:

```
$data['form'] = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('\Drupal\palom_services\Form\ServicesForm', $service_type);
```

Answer (score 7):

I have tried the Clive's solution, however, it breaks the interface of `FormInterface`.

In the `\Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm()` method, the code is the following:

```
  public function getForm($form_arg) {
    $form_state = new FormState();

    $args = func_get_args();
    // Remove $form_arg from the arguments.
    unset($args[0]);
    $form_state->addBuildInfo('args', array_values($args));

    return $this->buildForm($form_arg, $form_state);
  }
```

So you don't need to modify the signature of `buildForm()`, you should access these values from `$form_state`.

It should be usable this way: `$form_state->getBuildInfo()['args']`

Comment: Really good and clean method.